# using JS actions on an image map

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to have 4 small squares (of different colors) to form one big square. When you hover over any square, the color gets brighter. And every square has an image map with multiple links.

I used this method to do the hovering task

```
<img src="green_off.png" id="green" onmouseover="document.getElementById('green').src='green_on.png'" onmouseout="document.getElementById('green').src='green_off.png'">
```

Now if I use the image map with that, the onmouseover doesn't work. How to achieve both at the same time?

This is the code I have:

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<img src="green_off.png" id="green" usemap="#greenmap" onmouseover="document.getElementById('green').src='green_on.png'" onmouseout="document.getElementById('green').src='green_off.png'" border=0>
<img src="blue_off.png" id="blue" onmouseover="document.getElementById('blue').src='blue_on.png'" onmouseout="document.getElementById('blue').src='blue_off.png'"border=0>
<br>
<img src="yellow_off.png" id="yellow" onmouseover="document.getElementById('yellow').src='yellow_on.png'" onmouseout="document.getElementById('yellow').src='yellow_off.png'" border=0>
<map name="greenmap">
 <area shape="circle" coords="100,100,20" href="https://www.google.com">
 <area shape="circle" coords="300,100,20" href="www.youtube.com">
 <area shape="circle" coords="100,300,20" href="www.facebook.com">
 <area shape="circle" coords="300,300,20" href="www.instagram.com">
</map>
</body>
</html>
```

Update: I figured out what the problem is. The buttons on the image map were too big. I made them smaller and now it works. However, the mousover action only works so far as it's on the unmapped part of the image. Is there a way for it to work on the buttons as well?

Update & Fixed: I just added a onmouseover action to the map and now it's all good. Here's my fixed code.

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<img src="green_off.png" id="green" usemap="#greenmap" onmouseover="document.getElementById('green').src='green_on.png'" onmouseout="document.getElementById('green').src='green_off.png'" border=0>
<img src="blue_off.png" id="blue" onmouseover="document.getElementById('blue').src='blue_on.png'" onmouseout="document.getElementById('blue').src='blue_off.png'" border=0>
<br>
<img src="yellow_off.png" id="yellow" onmouseover="document.getElementById('yellow').src='yellow_on.png'" onmouseout="document.getElementById('yellow').src='yellow_off.png'" border=0>
<map name="greenmap" onmouseover="document.getElementById('green').src='green_on.png'">
 <area shape="circle" coords="100,100,20" href="https://www.google.com">
 <area shape="circle" coords="300,100,20" href="www.youtube.com">
 <area shape="circle" coords="100,300,20" href="www.facebook.com">
 <area shape="circle" coords="300,300,20" href="www.instagram.com">
</map>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What did you try using javascript or jquery ? Can you show us some code ?

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that on the first image the onmouseover action is to set the opacity of the image to 1. But this is the default value so there is no change, actually. It looks like it's not working because it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Oh, that was a mistake. I changed that img tag to 
<img src="green_off.png" id="green" usemap="#greenmap" onmouseover="document.getElementById('green').src='green_on.png'" onmouseout="document.getElementById('green').src='green_off.png'">
but it's still not working